# Qooxdoo: how to make a form validation on a complex form?

Tags: forms, validation, qooxdoo

I have this form:

https://github.com/totty90/production01_server/blob/master/node_modules/production/client/production/source/class/production/views/insertWorkAsManager/Index.js

https://github.com/totty90/production01_server/tree/master/node_modules/production/client/production/source/class/production/views/insertWorkAsManager

It's not exactly a simple form not even a form yet. It's just a bunch of widgets, but I would like to take advance of the validations on the various fields. How do you suggest to do? As I cant directly apply the Form example in my "form".

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

qooxdoo supports validation for items in the from and the from in total. This offers the opportunity to validate everything you want. Either you check on a single field basis or on a combination. Check out the following demo which showcases most of the features:

http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.0.1/demobrowser/index.html#ui~FormValidator.html